# How to completely uninstall TortoiseSVN 1.8.4

Tags: svn, openssl, tortoisesvn, uninstallation

I was updating some machines and decided to upgrade TortoiseSVN to the latest version.

On my main dev box, every time I attempt a checkout I get SSL errors. I have searched and searched and the only thing anyone has said which was helpful is that it's either the network stack is corrupted or there is something wrong with the ssl libraries.

All I know is that on this machine, I did not add or remove anything else. If I use the TortoiseSVN uninstaller, when I go to reinstall the procedure is never the same as the first time I installed. So it is leaving remnants behind in the uninstall.

Anyone know how to completely remove Tortoise and all it's support files?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the error?

Comment: I'm sorry, it was too long ago and I deleted the log. 

It was an SSL error of all things.

Comment: ah, I see the error in your another question here. Most likely the error won't occur with the latest TortoiseSVN 1.8.7 which is built against newer `serf` library.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by installing a Pre-1.7 version of Tortoise on all of my machines. This is not ideal since the 1.6.x versions have issues as well.

If anyone knows why SSL errors are showing up in the 1.8.x versions please let me know.